# Sharepoint Server Standard 2010 - Teamsite Assistance

Tags: permissions, web-part

We are creating a simple, clean, functional teamsite on our intranet using SharePoint Server Standard 2010, using shared documents library for various folders and subfolders.

In a few of these subfolders, we would like to insert projects tasks and contact list. Problem is, these show also on the front page and through out the sharepoint 2010 teamsite, meaning a lot of scrolling, repetitveness etc.

Minimising is an option using the edit webpart, but ideally we want this shown only in the subfolders.

Can this be disabled or any alternatives, opinions, is this a permissions issue?

Your answers, feedback is greatly appreciated on this work in progress stage of our intranet.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tasks and contacts I definitely wouldn't have them in the same library, even if they're in separate folders. It's fundamentally bad information architecture.

Keep them in separately libraries and make appropriate use of content types to aggregate your content.

Comment: Thanks and much appreciated James, we havent considered that.

Comment: Looks like the appreciation did not extend as far as an upvote. +1 from me.